# Spark Dataframe - Write a new record for a change in VALUE for a particular KEY group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Need to write a row when there is change in "AMT" column for a particular "KEY" group.

Eg :

```
Scenarios-1: For KEY=2, first change is 90 to 20, So need to write a record with value (20-90). 
Similarly the next change for the same key group is 20 to 30.5, So again need to write another record with value (30.5 - 20) 

Scenarios-2: For KEY=1, only one record for this KEY group so write as is

Scenarios-3: For KEY=3, Since the same AMT value exists twice, so write once
```

How can this be implemented ? Using window functions or by groupBy agg functions?

Sample Input Data :

```
val DF1 = List((1,34.6),(2,90.0),(2,90.0),(2,20.0),(2,30.5),(3,89.0),(3,89.0)).toDF("KEY", "AMT")

DF1.show(false)
+-----+-------------------+
|KEY  |AMT                |
+-----+-------------------+
|1    |34.6               |
|2    |90.0               |
|2    |90.0               |
|2    |20.0               |----->[ 20.0 - 90.0 = -70.0 ]
|2    |30.5               |----->[ 30.5 - 20.0 =  10.5 ]
|3    |89.0               |
|3    |89.0               |
+-----+-------------------+
```

Expected Values :

```
scala> df2.show()
+----+--------------------+
|KEY | AMT                |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |       34.6         |-----> As Is 
|  2 |       -70.0        |----->[ 20.0 - 90.0 = -70.0 ]
|  2 |       10.5         |----->[ 30.5 - 20.0 =  10.5 ]
|  3 |       89.0         |-----> As Is, with one record only
+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: `2, 90.0` is there twice in the source dataframe but not in the expected dataframe. Is that how you want the solution ?

Comment: Yes philantrovert. That’s how we are expecting..Basically we need to capture any changes in AMT column

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to solve it in pyspark not in scala.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w1=Window().partitionBy("key").orderBy("key")
DF4 =spark.createDataFrame([(1,34.6),(2,90.0),(2,90.0),(2,20.0),(2,30.5),(3,89.0),(3,89.0)],["KEY", "AMT"])
DF4.createOrReplaceTempView('keyamt')
DF7=spark.sql('select distinct key,amt from keyamt where key in ( select key from (select key,count(distinct(amt))dist from keyamt group by key) where dist=1)')
DF8=DF4.join(DF7,DF4['KEY']==DF7['KEY'],'leftanti').withColumn('new_col',((lag('AMT',1).over(w1)).cast('double') ))
DF9=DF8.withColumn('new_col1', ((DF8['AMT']-DF8['new_col'].cast('double'))))
DF9.withColumn('new_col1', ((DF9['AMT']-DF9['new_col'].cast('double')))).na.fill(0)
DF9.filter(DF9['new_col1'] !=0).select(DF9['KEY'],DF9['new_col1']).union(DF7).orderBy(DF9['KEY'])
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+
|KEY|new_col1|
+---+--------+
|  1|    34.6|
|  2|   -70.0|
|  2|    10.5|
|  3|    89.0|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your logic using `window` function with combination of `when`, `lead`, `monotically_increasing_id()` for *ordering* and `withColumn` api as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("KEY").orderBy("rowNo")
val tempdf = DF1.withColumn("rowNo", monotonically_increasing_id())
tempdf.select($"KEY", when(lead("AMT", 1).over(windowSpec).isNull || (lead("AMT", 1).over(windowSpec)-$"AMT").as("AMT")===lit(0.0), $"AMT").otherwise(lead("AMT", 1).over(windowSpec)-$"AMT").as("AMT")).show(false)
```